# How Can Return Dynamic methods with various parameters in C#

Tags: c#, methods, dynamic, func

is it possible return dynamic methods with various parameters with Func or any methods like this

```
    public enum MethodType
    {
        T1,
        T2
    }
    Func<????, IRequest> MethodGenerator(MethodType methodType, Dictionary<Type, string> args)
    {
        switch (methodType)
        {
            case MethodType.T1:
                return Method1;
            case MethodType.T2:
                return Method2;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public IRequest Method1(string token, int state)
    {
        // Some Code
        return null;
    }
    public IRequest Method2(string token, int state, string name)
    {
        // Some Code
        return null;
    }
MethodGenerator(new Dictonary<type, string>(){MethodType.T1, {string, "token"},{int, "state"}}
```

and finally the last line return **Method1**?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by decorate?

Comment: a function that return functions with various arguments

Comment: You can do that but they will be awkward to call if the number of arguments varies as it does in your example. Also, since there is no instance, you might as well just make them `static` and reference or assign them directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dynamic way to represent the definition of inputs for a Func but rather the type you define can be dynamic.

Given the following objects:

```
public enum MethodType
{
    T1,
    T2
}

public class TestRequest
{
    public IRequest Method1(string token, int state)
    {
        // Some Code
        return new Request1();
    }
    public IRequest Method2(string token, int state, string name)
    {
        // Some Code
        return new Request2();
    }
}

public interface IRequest
{
    string RequestName();
}

public class Request1 : IRequest
{
    public string RequestName() => "Request1";
}

public class Request2 : IRequest
{
    public string RequestName() => "Request2";
}
```

You can then have the following class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly Dictionary<MethodType, Func<object[], IRequest>> _definitions;

    public TestClass(Dictionary<MethodType, Func<object[], IRequest>> definitions)
    {
        _definitions = definitions;
    }

    public IRequest MethodGenerator(MethodType methodType,
        params object[] args)
    {
        return _definitions[methodType](args);
    }
}
```

I have written the following test to demonstrate the functionality:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var definitions = new Dictionary<MethodType, Func<object[], IRequest>>
        {
            {
                MethodType.T1, objects =>
                {
                    var testRequest = new TestRequest();
                    return testRequest.Method1((string)objects[0], (int)objects[1]);
                }
            },
            {
                MethodType.T2, objects =>
                {
                    var testRequest = new TestRequest();
                    return testRequest.Method2((string)objects[0], (int)objects[1], (string)objects[2]);
                }
            }
        };

        var testClass = new TestClass(definitions);
        var result1 = testClass.MethodGenerator(MethodType.T1, "test", 1);
        var result2 = testClass.MethodGenerator(MethodType.T2, "test2", 1, "test2");

        Assert.AreEqual("Request1", result1.RequestName());
        Assert.AreEqual("Request2", result2.RequestName());
    }
```